# Picklist value selection that will populate formula field date

Tags: formula, opportunity, picklist, formula-field, date

I am trying to make a formula date field with will show Today's date ifa specific picklist value is selected. Here is what I have come up with

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Debit_Success__c , "Suspended"),TODAY())
```

I am getting an error that 
"Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 2"

Any idea about if I am missing something here will be much appreciated

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify one more parameter in IF condition, with the value that needs to be shown if the condition is not satisfied.

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Debit_Success__c , "Suspended"),TODAY(),TODAY()-5)
```

Replace TODAY()-5 with your value.

Comment: If i donot want to give any other value, can  put "null" then?? for example IF(ISPICKVAL(Debit_Success__c , "Suspended"),TODAY(),null)

Comment: Yeah. Please try. If not null you should be able to put ""